# how to establish the connection between nodejs and mongodb on aws lambda?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda

I am using MongoDB database and Aws lambda function in my project. When  i tried access Mongodb dataabse through Aws lambda node js function, i get some error. find the below code

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
if (err) throw err;
});
```

I get some error like this below:

```
Response:
{
"errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'mongodb'",
"errorType": "Error",
"stackTrace": [
"Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)",
"Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
"require (internal/module.js:11:18)",
"Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:1:81)",
"Module._compile (module.js:652:30)",
"Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)",
"Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
"tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
"Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)"
```

]
}

How to connect mongdb and aws lambda function through node.js???

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to npm install the module.
Try

```
npm install mongodb
```

Comment: where i will install the module

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here you need to address:

- You need to install `mongodb` as fly mentioned above. I am not sure how you are deploying to AWS Lambda, but you usually install it locally, adding it to your `package.json` file. Then once you deploy, AWS reads that file and installs it on your Lambda instance.
- Your Lambda instance will not be able to reach your localhost
  database instance because it is local to your computer only. You can set one up here at
  https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas and then use that database URL to
  connect from your AWS Lambda instance.
- If you are working on your localhost, your database url should be
  `"mongodb://localhost:27017/";`. You only include the
  `username:password` portion when you are in fact using them.